# Create gradient blurred background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, inkscape

I want to create a blurred gradient background effect similar to the designs below. How can I do this using Inkscape or Photoshop/Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Use the gradient tool. These appear to be simple radial gradients. This is possible in nearly any graphic design software such as, Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Design, Photoshop, or GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a simple gradient in **Illustrator**. If one wishes more control, then a [Gradient Mesh](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html) may help.

[image]

---

For **Photoshop** one just uses the Gradient Tool with subtle foreground/background colors and click-drags.

[image]

---

The key is to use subtle color changes. In these images the difference between the dark (black) and the color is minute, merely reducing the amount of black (or increasing saturation) so more of the color shows.